# Can square mean a reounded number?

Tags: vocabulary, idiomatic-language

Can square mean a rounded number as in "Can you knock 50 dollars off the price and make it a thousand dollars square"? The seller is asking 1050 dollar for the merchandize and the buyer is trying to negotiate down to $1000.

Comment: Though I've not heard that usage, it might be accepted in some regions. It seems understandable but not colloquial (others: please let me know if this is used in your area).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I've heard *square* used for *even* (or *tidy*) on more than one occasion. It's not as common as just saying *$1000* ***even***, but I know it to mean the same thing. So, I'd certainly say it's colloquial.